# Pandas DataFrame indexing out of order

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, datetime, indexing

I have the following Pandas DataFrame:

```
Year        Bananas     Apples

2015 - 1    151235.0    NaN
2015 - 10   517326.0    NaN
2015 - 11   497511.0    NaN
2015 - 12   503372.0    NaN
2015 - 13   524244.0    NaN
2015 - 14   505785.0    11588.0
2015 - 15   493530.0    19170.0
2015 - 16   511167.0    18304.0
2015 - 17   605087.0    19030.0
2015 - 18   523477.0    20732.0
2015 - 19   410203.0    22032.0
2015 - 2    410268.0    NaN
2015 - 20   436890.0    21447.0
2015 - 21   412306.0    21957.0
2015 - 22   390683.0    23072.0
```

I wish to use the "Year" column as the index for my DataFrame, but the sorting is out of order.  As can be seen, the values for "2015 - 2" should be before "2015 - 10".

All the values in the column "Year" are strings. The format is intended as [Year, Week number]. I would like to keep this formatting, as I do not have any other information besides year and week number.

I have tried using the pd.sort_values command to sort my values in ascending order, but that did not solve the problem. I have also tried setting the "Year" column as my index and using the pd.sort_index command, but that did not work either.

I'm new to Python and Pandas, so any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately pandas sort function don't `key` argument to provide custom compare function. But you can add new column based on "Year" and sort data with it.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Year': ['2015 - 10', '2015 - 1', '2015 - 2'],
    'bla': [3, 1, 2]
})

df['index'] = df['Year'].apply(lambda x: list(map(int, x.split(' - '))))
print(df)
df = df.sort_values('index')
print(df)
df = df.drop('index', axis=1)  # drop index if you don't need it
print(df)
```

output:

```
        Year  bla       index
0  2015 - 10    3  [2015, 10]
1   2015 - 1    1   [2015, 1]
2   2015 - 2    2   [2015, 2]
        Year  bla       index
1   2015 - 1    1   [2015, 1]
2   2015 - 2    2   [2015, 2]
0  2015 - 10    3  [2015, 10]
        Year  bla
1   2015 - 1    1
2   2015 - 2    2
0  2015 - 10    3
```